# How to auto-detect devices connected to COM ports

Tags: c#

I want to auto detect devices connected to the COM ports of my computer. Being able to use the SerialPort class allows me to get the list of available COM ports easily.

I want to iterate through them and poll(send a command) to each port and wait for a response. However it seems that most tutorials suggested to use the DataReceived event. I am lost at how to do a serial send followed by waiting for xx amount of seconds till I receive a response from the device.

Comment: Well, haven't you written any code yet? Already saw this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8605/Serial-Communication-using-C-and-Whidbey ?

Answer (score 3):

The DataReceived event is very nice when you need to talk to devices that can send something at a very unpredictable time.  You don't have to burn up a thread that just blocks and waits for the device to send something.

But that's completely the opposite of what you're trying achieve, you *do* expect to receive something.  So don't use DataReceived, use Read() with the ReadTimeout property set to a suitably low value.  Now it is simple.  Also consider using the DsrHolding property.  It is true when there's a device attached to the port and it is powered-up.

I should note that doing this is rather dangerous.  You have no idea what kind of devices are attached to the machine, it is rather tricky to send them something they were not designed to process.  If whatever "are you there?" command you send just happens to mean to a robot controller "go home with 1G acceleration" then somebody is going to get hurt easily.  You cannot do this in any kind of industrial setting.

By far the best way is to make it somebody else's responsibility to get this right.  Add an option menu that lets the user set the port name.  And settings, they matter a lot too and there's no way to auto-detect them.  The option dialog could have a "help me find the device" button, now it is safe *and* useful.

Comment: Does WMI `ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()` count as "are you there?". I can totally see the point on your robot accident scenario, and as such I would like to know if `ManagementObjectSearcher` is safe regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) have feature to query devices on COM, there is also [Linq to WMI](http://linq2wmi.codeplex.com/) library that could be helpful

Hope this helps